# print a variable value in str_replace function

Tags: php, wordpress

below is my code.

All is okay but, in image alt tag, its showing `$image_alt`, instead value of that variable. How can I print the value of the variable inside this function?

Kind regards.

```
$image_alt = $attributes["caption"];
$image_src= Str_replace('src="', 'alt=$image_alt  src="',$image_src);
```

Comment: Use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) in order to print out the variable value.

Comment: You can print out the double quote after `src` by escaping it. `"alt=$image_alt  src=\""`

Comment: I have written now in that way, 
$image_src= Str_replace("src='", "alt=$image_alt  src='",$image_src); Did you mean that?@Ahmad